# dplyr join by exclusion?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

When using the various `join` functions from `dplyr` you can either join all variables with the same name (by default) or specify those ones using `by = c("a" = "b")`. Is there a way to join by exclusion? For example, I have 1000 variables in two data frames and I want to join them by 999 of them, leaving one out. I don't want to do `by = c("a1" = "b1", ...,"a999" = "b999")`. Is there a way to join by excluding the one variable that is not used?

Ok, using this example from one answer:

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data_frame(alala= LETTERS[1:3], skks= letters[1:3], sskjs= 
                  letters[1:3], val = rnorm(3))
df2 <- data_frame(alala= LETTERS[1:3], skks= letters[1:3], sskjs= 
                   letters[1:3], val = rnorm(3))
```

I want to join them using all variables excluding `val`. I'm looking for a more general solution. Assuming there are 1000 variables and I only remember the name of the one that I want to exclude in the join, while not knowing the index of that variable. How can I perform the join while only knowing the variable names to exclude. I understand I can find the column index first but is there a simply way to add exclusions in `by =`?

Comment: Although your question seems clear, please share a minimal reproducible example that mimics your problem.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @JianghuiDu Note that if you do not know the index of the column to exclude, and the columns to match are not named the same in both data frames, how do you know that you will correctly pair the columns if there is no pattern to the names?

Comment: sorry, my fault. these names should be the same. Corrected in the example.

Comment: Your example has mismatched lengths in df2

Answer (score 3):

We create a named vector to do this

```
library(dplyr)
grps <- setNames(paste0("b", 1:999), paste0("a", 1:999))
```

Note the 'grps' vector is created with `paste` as the OP's post suggested a pattern.  If there is no pattern, but we know the column that is not to be grouped

```
nogroupColumn <- "someColumn"
grps <- setNames(setdiff(names(df1), nogroupColumn), 
                   setdiff(names(df2), nogroupColumn))

inner_join(df1, df2, by = grps)
```

Using a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data_frame(a1 = LETTERS[1:3], a2 = letters[1:3], val = rnorm(3))
df2 <- data_frame(b1 = LETTERS[3:4], b2 = letters[3:4], valn = rnorm(2))
grps <- setNames(paste0("b", 1:2), paste0("a", 1:2))

inner_join(df1, df2, by = grps)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  a1    a2      val   valn
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 C     c     0.420 -0.584
```

Comment: OK. The question I'm thinking is not this simple. In this example the variable names are simply and you can do this, but what about the variable names has no "rules" like in his simple example? I guess my point is that I know the name that I do not want to join, while these ones that I want to join are too many and I can't remember all their names.

Comment: @JianghuiDu  In your post, there seems to be a pattern.  If you know the index of columns then, `grps <- setNames(names(df1)[-1], names(df2)[-1])`

Comment: Assuming I only know the name but not the index.

Comment: Super clever. I see the new question reads: "Assuming there are 1000 variables and I only remember the name of the one that I want to exclude in the join, while not knowing the index of that variable."

Answer (score 2):

To exclude a certain field(s), you need to identify the index of the columns you want. Here's one way:

```
which(!names(df1) %in% "sskjs" ) #<this excludes the column "sskjs"
[1] 1 2 4                        #<and shows only the desired index columns
```

Use `unite` to create a join_id in each dataframe, and join by it.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
    unite(join_id, which(!names(.) %in% "sskjs"), remove = F)

df2 <- df2 %>% 
    unite(join_id, which(!names(.) %in% "sskjs"), remove = F)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "join_id" )
```